# Alternatives to Bonjour for Windows

Tags: zeroconf

I'm looking to implement a ZeroConf application for Windows. I've noticed Bonjour and Mono.Zeroconf but was wondering if there were any decent alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There is a python implementation of zeroconf called pyzeroconf: https://github.com/paulsm/pyzeroconf, that is pretty useful, though there are some bugs in it that you will have to fix and is not implemented for ipv6.